# Syntax error or access violation: 1064 Erreur de syntaxe

Tags: zend-framework2, doctrine, php-5.4

When trying to run this code in Zend 2 with doctrine 2 with this Script  :

```
$query = $entityManager->createQuery('SELECT u FROM  \Synchro\Entity\Group u WHERE u.namegroup=:namegroup');
            $query->setParameters(array(
                    'namegroup' =>$nameGroup
                    ));

$datagroup['nameGroup'] = "Group_".$companyinfo['cprenom']."".$companyinfo ['cnom'];
```

i get this Error :

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 Erreur de syntaxe prÃ¨s de 'group g0_ WHERE g0_.nameGroup = 'GroupPETIT'' Ã  la ligne 1

i ver_dumped the  `$nameGroup` i get  string 'GroupPETIT',
how can i resolved that
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please try to provide as much details to your question as possible: a) more than one line of code (e.g. how is it used, where is the sql query submitted), b) the contents of the `$companyinfo` variable and others shown in your example c) which database & frameworks you are using.

Comment: paste here your $query->getQuery()->getSQL() result, at least.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `$companyinfo ['cprenom']` is an array. Trying dumping it, and also there is space between `$companyInfo` and `['cprenom']`. Hope there is no space in the code.

Comment: i Have always This Error:SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 Erreur de syntaxe prÃ¨s de 'group g0_ WHERE g0_.nameGroup = 'GroupPETIT'' i do this query in doctrine i used Zend 2 :$query = $entityManager->createQuery('SELECT u FROM  \Synchro\Entity\Group u WHERE u.namegroup=:namegroup');
   $query->setParameters(array(
     'namegroup' =>$nameGroup
     ));how can i resolve this Issue thanks in advance